# Finding a relevant subset of a set of 3d points

Tags: sql-server, database, math, 3d, statistics

In my **sql server** database I have a set of data values say 'A'. It has some 6000 odd rows and 3 columns as points on x-axis,y-axis and z-axis.

I have to deduce a subset 'B' of only 100 points that resembles the data of set 'A' most closely removing the outliers (For ex. If there are just 2 points in the 3d space somewhere they should be ignored but if there is a cluster of points somewhere they should be represented by a point or two as applicable).

So can you all please help me create a procedure or function for this.
I tried on the net and myself as well but did not found a correct solution that I can implement.

Comment: It isn't completely clear what you want here.  It sounds like you want do a clustering analysis of some sort, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. I need a cluster of points most closely to what I already have

Comment: I would handle this in R using a clustering package, not SQL Server.  SQL is for heavy lifting of data, not so much complex data mining.

Comment: But the thing is I have to do it in sql only. I can although try to implement the logic in SQL if I get the logic in R.

Answer (score 1):

You need an algorithm for polyline simplification. Perhaps the most popular one is [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)

> The purpose of the algorithm is, given a curve composed of line
>   segments, to find a similar curve with fewer points.

It is not clear yet - what to do with outliers - probably you need some smoothing or another filtering (because D_P algo tries to preserve them)

Comment: I had searched this also but the thing is it will actually preserve all the outliers and also will remove the concentrated clouds where as they are very important

Comment: So you have to define clear criteria - what points are outliers, and what are important. Note that D-P criteria of perpendicular distance might be used for filtering.

Comment: I suggest that it is worth to try two stage treatment -1. filtering outliers that have too large perpendicular distance 2. D-P simplification

Comment: The Problem with D-P are the following
1. Calculating distances between a line in 3-d Space with all the other points is difficult in terms of processing.
2.Clusters will be removed  and outliers would be included.

To define clearly.........
A group of points in a location where no. of points is less then a particular threshold are outliers.
And those clusters having points more than the threshold are important.

The new set of points should clearly define where there was more concentration earlier

Comment: Seems you need clustering first and remove too small clusters